# icon selector using two view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios4, uiviewcontroller

Need help with the following. I am creating two different combinations of view/controllers that allow me to add/edit a set of information , think tasks or some type of to-do. I have all the data capture/store functionality working.

I decided that it would be nice to have an icon associated to these tasks. So the icon would show up in the UITableview. I commissioned 18 customer 44x44 icons that would be added tot he table.

But there is where I'm stuck:

I was to add/edit views to have the capability to select an icon to attach to the tasks. In order to do so, i added a 44x44 round-rect button with one of the images as a default. I wanted to have that button trigger another view with the 18 icons so the user selects one and it passes control back to the main view and updates de selected icon appropriately.

I created this little 18 icon view together with the main view, which is based on a scroll view. I configured the little icon view to be hidden.

But I have no idea if the little view should be a subview of the main view, who should be the file owner, how do I make it appear hidden as the main view is displayed and toggle t as needed...

I am stumped. Anyone done something like this? Ideas? Things I completely messing up, you can think of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't want the views to flip but have the little view with the icons appear floating on top of the main view while the picking process is active and then dissappear to the "background".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to hide and show the view is to adjust the "alpha" property on the view. If you set the alpha of the little view to 0 it will be hidden, and when you set it to 1 it will be showing. So in your awakeFromNib function (or wherever you are doing initialization) you can add the littleView and set the alpha to 0 so it starts hidden. I suggest adding the littleview to your mainview unless for some reason the little view will have any part of it outside of the mainview. Then, when the user selects the icon to change it, you can set the alpha to 1. Finally, when the user chooses from the view, you would set the alpha back to 0.

Note:
This is not the most efficient use of memory because the view is technically always around. So if you think that you will be low on memory I would suggest creating the view programmatically when needed and removing it from mainview when the user is done. (But only do this if you think it will be an uncommon task because creating the view with a bunch of images will probably be a relatively expensive operation).